# Should I use git's branches to keep different versions of my code?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository where I put my Data Structures and Algorithms (DSA) code. As of right now, my `master` branch contains the DSA code written in C++.

I've been wanting to implement some DSA in other languages, like C and Python. I intend to make a new branch in my repository and then reimplement everything in C or Python.

So, is branching to make different versions of my code a good practice? If I want to write some of the DSA in different languages, what should I do?

Comment: It is better to create folder structure like:  `/Algorithms/DSA/` under DSA you can create different files for different languages like /Algorithms/DSA/dsa_in_c, /Algorithms/DSA/dsa_in_py and then push to `git`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the ***version controls*** (*git, svn, etc*) are designed for this type of case: **have different versions of your code**.

For example, you can have a branch called `MasterDSAC` (*for all code writing in C++*) and `MaterDSAPy`(*for all code writing in Phyton*) :

```
git branch checkout -b MasterDSAC
git branch checkout -b MasterPy
```

Remember that for a good practice you must have in `master` **that code that to a lesser extent contains a bug and therefore be the least**.

Disadvantages :

- Code maintenance
- Pulls and merge errors

Advantages :

- Possibility of cloning by branches
- Greater availability of code and ordering